# Pytorch stateful custom loss function

Tags: pytorch

I have a stateful custom loss function in pytorch as follows:

```
class PositionLossNormalized(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self, beta, epsilon=1e-8):
    super(PositionLossNormalized, self).__init__()
    self.beta = beta
    self.beta_t = beta
    self.running_avg = 0.0
    self.epsilon = epsilon

def forward(self, targets, predictions):
    sqr_diff = torch.square(targets - predictions)
    Pxj = torch.mean(sqr_diff, dim=-1)
    Pxj2 = torch.square(Pxj)
    
    avg_Pxj = torch.mean(Pxj)
    avg_Pxj2 = torch.mean(Pxj2)
    
    self.running_avg = self.beta * self.running_avg + (1.0 - self.beta) * avg_Pxj2.item()
    loss_val = avg_Pxj / (np.sqrt(self.running_avg / (1.0 - self.beta_t)) + self.epsilon)
    
    self.beta_t = self.beta * self.beta_t
    
    return loss_val
```

Would this work considering I have a numpy operation (viz. np.sqrt). My thinking is that the I am just scaling the value of avg_Pxj (which is autodiff-able) with a python scalar, and this should not break the autodiff chain. I ran the code and pytorch proceeds without any error. Am I right in doing this ? Or, should I change the code to use only pytorch functions as below :

```
class PositionLossNormalized(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self, beta, epsilon=1e-8):
    super(PositionLossNormalized, self).__init__()
    self.beta = torch.as_tensor(beta, dtype=torch.float32)
    self.beta_t = torch.as_tensor(beta, dtype=torch.float32)
    self.running_avg = torch.as_tensor(0.0, dtype=torch.float32)
    self.epsilon = torch.as_tensor(epsilon, dtype=torch.float32)

def forward(self, targets, predictions):
    sqr_diff = torch.square(targets - predictions)
    Pxj = torch.mean(sqr_diff, dim=-1)
    Pxj2 = torch.square(Pxj)
    
    avg_Pxj = torch.mean(Pxj)
    avg_Pxj2 = torch.mean(Pxj2)
    
    self.running_avg = self.beta * self.running_avg + (1.0 - self.beta) * avg_Pxj2.clone().detach()
    loss_val = avg_Pxj / (torch.sqrt(self.running_avg / (1.0 - self.beta_t)) + self.epsilon)
    
    self.beta_t = self.beta * self.beta_t
    
    return loss_val

def reset(self):
    self.beta_t = self.beta
```

Thanks!

Comment: Solved. Refer: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-loss-functions/29387/124

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Refer: discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-loss-functions/29387/124

Comment: Can you add the solution to this answer, as well? (Don't just rely on an external link.)